# .AsNoTracking() always on for certains DbSets for entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Can I turn off tracking for a certain DbSet all the time without doing it on the context?  I dont want to have to always remember to do it when pulling a query.

```
 var locations = _venuesRepository.DataContext.Courts.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a feature of EF Core.

You can set the `DbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior` Property.
Logically, there also is an `AsTracking()` method in Core.

But when you are asking for the regular EF (6.x) then no, there is no such feature as far as I know.